# Unusual notation - python

Tags: python

It might be a very simple question. I was running a python code, and I got an error message as such :

```
File "/home/mbenchoufi/brisket/../brisket/views.py", line 11, in <module>
from influence.forms import SearchForm

ImportError: No module named forms
```

The problem is first that I have indeed a file called views.py in /home/myname/brisket/ but I don''t understand the notation : /home/myname/brisket/../brisket/views.py

Do I have a path config problem and what does this notation means ?

Btw, a really weird thing is that I have a file called forms.py, in the influence folder, and in this file a I have a class called SearchForm... How can the error message can be ?

Answer (score 5):

This is not a Python-specific notation, it's a UNIX filesystem notation. `..` in a UNIX path means "back up one directory," so for example, in this case, `/home/myname/brisket/..` is equivalent to just `/home/myname`.

The reason Python displays the filename in this way might be that your `sys.path` has actually has `/home/myname/brisket/..` in it for some reason. It's not a problem, since Python will be able to follow the `..`s in the path just fine.

What this error message is telling you is that, while processing the file `/home/myname/brisket/../brisket/views.py` (which is the same file as `/home/myname/brisket/views.py`) there is a line of code

```
from influence.forms import SearchForm
```

which caused an error. Specifically, it's an `ImportError`, meaning that the file `influence/forms.py` wasn't found (or could not be read) by Python's import mechanism. You should check the value of `sys.path` in your Python program to make sure that the parent directory of `influence/` is in the list, and make sure that the file is readable. (Also make sure that `influence/__init__.py` exists, though I'm not sure that particular problem would cause the error you're seeing.)

Comment: but the really weird thing is that I have a file called forms.py, in the influence folder, and in this file a I have a class called SearchForm... How can it be ?

Comment: I couldn't say, since you haven't provided any information about what error you're actually getting.

Answer (score 2):

```
"/home/myname/brisket/../brisket/views.py"
```

is equivalent to

```
"/home/myname/brisket/views.py"
```

The cause might be an entry in you PYTHONPATH, e.g. like

```
export PYTHONPATH="$HOME/../brisket:$PYTHONPATH"
```

http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH

The above approach has the benefit of working for other users, while not requiring an absolute path to /home. Write it like

```
export PYTHONPATH="/home/brisket:$PYTHONPATH"
```

to get simpler paths